# Where can I edit the footer divs/classes drupal7

Tags: drupal-7

I need to edit our footer fourth column on our Drupal 7 site, however I can't find the file where this is located. I have checked the page.tpl.php however it's not in here. I need to edit the images in our 'footer contact info' section so I need to be able to edit the class?

I can't post an Image as I need 10 reputation to do so.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the footer is generated by a file (and not a block, for example), why not use your text editor to "find in files". Notepad++ is good for this - just search the entire directory for a phrase.

It's not a great solution to your problem but it might help you to understand the structure of the site a little better.

Comment: I've done this searched all folders in my theme directory for <p class ="email"> and returned nothing - maybe I'm way off?

Comment: Found where I need to add a new css class however, it's not recognizing it? any suggestions, do I need to declare this new class somewhere other than style.css?

Comment: First make sure the class is added by inspecting the element. If it's in the HTML, you've edited the right file. Next check the class is in the correct CSS file (style.css) is most likely the right file.

Comment: Yes I can see the class when I inspect the element, it's just not recognizing it. Also been trying to get CKEditor working and just not working? I've downloaded the latest version and WYSIWYG I've checked that they are saved in the correct folders, cleared my cache including my broswers - are you familiar with this at all?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check other template files also. Depending on how your site was developed, they may have used separate page templates that render the footer. For example, check if there's a page--front.tpl.php (the front page template) or something similar that renders the footer.

Also be sure you're checking the correct page.tpl.php file, it should be in the templates folder within the theme your site is currently using.

Comment: Hi, Thanks I've checked all the template files in my theme folder and no luck! There is even a 'block-footer_fourthcolumn.tpl.php' file and still nothing! I'm quite lost at this stage!

Comment: It's a block? Is it listed under admin/structure/block with options to configure it?

Comment: It is a block but that only lets me edit the text - I need to edit the class. For example, <p class="email"> I need to add more like <p class="location"> etc?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're looking for exactly without seeing it myself, but if you're looking to just update the <p> classes in the block, you should still be able to do that under admin/structure/block, as long as you have some sort of WYSIWYG editor installed (https://drupal.org/project/WYSIWYG). The WYSIWYG editor will allow you to edit the source code of the block and add in <p> classes as needed.